# Getting invalid url hostname could not be parsed when executing ClientContext

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, error, url

I am trying to get List item values from SharePoint Online List using CSOM console application.

When executing it I am getting error:

> invalid URI: hostname could not be parsed error.

I am not sure what could be the issue. URL is valid only.

[image]

May I know what could be the issue?

Comment: Can you please check if the URL is correct or not? Can you add the URL format your are using ?

Comment: url format is https://{Rootsite}/sites/sitename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding there must be something wrong with the URL you written, maybe some extra spaces, `:` or `/` characters in your URL.

However you can get the `ClientContext` directly using below code (No need to use `Uri` object):

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SiteUrl");
```

Use below code to get the SharePoint Online site `ClientContext` and load all lists in your site (just for an example):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("SharePoint Online site URL:");
    string webSPOUrl = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("User Name:");
    string userName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Password:");
    SecureString password = FetchPasswordFromConsole();
    try
    {
        using (var context = new ClientContext(webSPOUrl))
        {
            context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, password);
            Web web = context.Web;
            context.Load(web.Lists,
                lists => lists.Include(list => list.Title,
                    list => list.Id));
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            foreach (List list in web.Lists)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("List title is: " + list.Title);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error is: " + ex.Message);
    }
}

private static SecureString FetchPasswordFromConsole()
{
    string password = "";
    ConsoleKeyInfo info = Console.ReadKey(true);
    while (info.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
    {
        if (info.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace)
        {
            Console.Write("*");
            password += info.KeyChar;
        }
        else if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            {
                password = password.Substring(0, password.Length - 1);
                int pos = Console.CursorLeft;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(pos - 1, Console.CursorTop);
                Console.Write(" ");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(pos - 1, Console.CursorTop);
            }
        }
        info = Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
    //Convert string to secure string  
    foreach (char c in password)
    {
        securePassword.AppendChar(c);
    }
    securePassword.MakeReadOnly();
    return securePassword;
}
```

**Note**: Your SharePoint Online site URL will be in format: `https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite`

**Official documentation**:

[Complete basic operations using SharePoint client library code](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code).

Comment: Initially i have tried as mentioned you, it failed and same error. then only passed url field. Again same error.

Comment: Ok, Check the updated answer. Try the given code and let me know if it works or if you face any issues.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh, your code is working fine. Not sure what is wrong with my code. :)

Comment: Welcome, glad it worked for you.